# Selecting right, left, above and below of input nodes with XPath

Tags: xpath

From this piece of HTML:

```
<form action="/signup" class="signup" method="post">
    <div class="field">
        <input type="text" class="text-input" autocomplete="off" name="user[name]" maxlength="20" placeholder="Nom complet">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <input type="text" class="text-input email-input" autocomplete="off" name="user[email]" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <input type="password" class="text-input" name="user[user_password]" placeholder="Mot de passe">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn signup-btn">
        S'inscrire
    </button>
</form>
```

Is it possible with XPath expression to return all to-right-of, to-left-of, below and above of each input element?

Comment: It's an example. However, I corrected. 
I mean position inside document. How to use `following-sibling`, `preceding-sibling`, `parent` & `child`?

Comment: use google for this :D a lot of examples there

Answer (score 1):

If you mean position inside document tree, to-right-of is right sibling (axis `following-sibling`), to-left-of is left sibling (axis `preceding-sibling`), above is parent (axis `parent`), below is child (or more children; axis `child`).

An axis is used as follows:

```
//button/preceding-sibling::*[last()]
```

This returns left siblings of all buttons in the document.

Two slashes (`//`) are a shortcut for `/descendant-or-self::node()`, which uses axis `descendant-or-self` and selects all subnodes of current node. At the beginning, the document is the current node, therefore `//` selects all nodes in the document. Thus `//button` (`/descendant-or-self::node()/button`) selects any button in the document. The step `preceding-sibling::*` selects all preceding siblings of each button. The `[last()]` part is explained below; it selects only the last preceding sibling of each button.

You can get first item from a collection by appending `[1]` to the XPath and last item by appending `[last()]`. These are shortcuts for `[position() = 1]` and `[position() = last()]` respectively.

Note that `child::` is implied when no axis is given. `//form/button` is the same as `//form/child::button`. Also there is an intuitive shortcut for `parent::*`, namely `..`.

Answer (score 0):

Palec Thank you for your explanations

For clarity I propose to use the Yahoo Finance website with this page http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=EURUSD=X

***to-right-of*** is right sibling (axis following-sibling)

For Text "EUR/USD (EURUSD=X)" to-right-of="CCY"

> Xpath Expression: .//h2[text()="EUR/USD (EURUSD=X)"]/following-sibling::*[1]

***to-left-of*** is left sibling (axis preceding-sibling)

For Text "CCY" to-left-of="EUR/USD (EURUSD=X)"

> Xpath Expression: .//span[text()="CCY  "]/preceding-sibling::*[1]

***above*** is parent (axis parent)

For Text "1.3588" above="EUR/USD (EURUSD=X)"

> Xpath Expression: .//span[text()="1.3588"]/parent::*[1] => **Bad result**

***below*** is child (axis child)

For Text "EUR/USD (EURUSD=X)" below="1.3588"

> Xpath Expression: .//h2[text()="EUR/USD (EURUSD=X)"]/child::*[1] => **No Result**

[jsfiddle Test](http://jsfiddle.net/gGbp5/)

```
var it = document.evaluate('//h2[text()="EUR/USD (EURUSD=X)"]/following-sibling::*[1]', document);

while (node = it.iterateNext()) { console.log(node); }
```

Comment: This is not an answer; however I get why you posted this info like that. This is exactly what my original comment under your question was about. From this, it is obvious that you want visual position, not document tree position. Sorry, there is no easy solution for you. To prevent further misleading theoretical discussion and [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/238706), what exactly are you trying to achieve? Is Yahoo! Finance info parsing the use case for you? Why do you need to use XPath?